# How to reduce MacBook Air 2013 1.7GHz CPU power consumption?

Tags: macbook-pro, power, battery

I'm seeking a way to reduce MacBook Air 2013 1.7GHz CPU power consumption -- or any MacBook for that matter -- to save battery life.  I want to vary the CPU power consumption variably, so that I can get "full speed" when I want and "better/best power savings" at other times.

Something akin to Linux's [cpuspeed](http://linux.die.net/man/8/cpuspeed%20cpuspeed) command (to reduce CPU clock frequency) would be helpful, but could be anything.  Note I'm seeking CPU-only power-consumption tips.  Please do not clutter answers with tips for non-CPU things like display brightness, avoiding Adobe Flash, employing different web browsers, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think the upcoming Mavericks OS update is supposed to help somewhat. http://www.apple.com/osx/preview/advanced-technologies.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using [Appriority](http://www.northernsoftworks.com/appriority.html)? It allows you to suspend and enable CPU usage as you switch between apps.